# How does EqualityComparer<T>.Default works internally?

Tags: c#

Consider T = string.

I'm curious if it uses something like: `typeof(EqualityComparer<T>).GetInterface("IEqualityComparer<T>");`

Any suggestions..

Comment: Why would it say `GetInterface` to get the `System.Type` object for the interface it implements itself? How would that be useful? It could just say `typeof(IEqualityComparer<T>)` if it needed that type somhow, but it doesn't need that. It needs to return an instance of `EqualityComparer<T>` that we can use. Since the class is `abstract`, this involves creating an instance of some non-abstract deriving class, and returning that. But maybe you really ask what the returned object behaves like? (At least that was what I answered below.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Courtesy of Reflector:

```
public static EqualityComparer<T> Default
{
    get
    {
        EqualityComparer<T> defaultComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.defaultComparer;
        if (defaultComparer == null)
        {
            defaultComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.CreateComparer();
            EqualityComparer<T>.defaultComparer = defaultComparer;
        }
        return defaultComparer;
    }
}

private static EqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer()
{
    RuntimeType c = (RuntimeType) typeof(T);
    if (c == typeof(byte))
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) new ByteEqualityComparer();
    }
    if (typeof(IEquatable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(c))
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter((RuntimeType) typeof(GenericEqualityComparer<int>), c);
    }
    if (c.IsGenericType && (c.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
    {
        RuntimeType type2 = (RuntimeType) c.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        if (typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type2 }).IsAssignableFrom(type2))
        {
            return (EqualityComparer<T>) RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter((RuntimeType) typeof(NullableEqualityComparer<int>), type2);
        }
    }
    if (c.IsEnum && (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(c) == typeof(int)))
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter((RuntimeType) typeof(EnumEqualityComparer<int>), c);
    }
    return new ObjectEqualityComparer<T>();
}
```

So as you can see if T = string it will return `GenericEqualityComparer<string>`.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful. It shows what non-public class is being used behind the scene, but it gives no information on how the non-public `GenericEqualityComparer<string>` class works. So who cares what the concrete realization of the abstract class is _named_?

Answer (score 2):

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` works by calling the `virtual` methods `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` which are defined by `System.Object` but may or may not be overridden by `T`.

Note that since the metods are `virtual`, an implementation of a more derived class than `T` may be used. For example:

```
EqualityComparer<object>.Default
  .Equals(new Uri("http://example.com/"), new Uri("http://example.com/"))
```

will return `true`, even if

```
Object.ReferenceEquals(new Uri("http://example.com/"), new Uri("http://example.com/"))
```

and

```
(object)new Uri("http://example.com/") == (object)new Uri("http://example.com/")
```

both return `false`.

In the case where `T` is `string`, the class `System.String` overloads the two methods in question and use an ordinal comparison. Thus in this case it should be equivalent to `System.StringComparer.Ordinal`. And of course `string` is a `sealed` class, so no other class could derive from `string` and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in some strange way.

Comment: Also - The advantage
is that first checks if T implements `IEquatable<T>` and if so, calls that implementation
instead, avoiding the boxing overhead. This is particularly useful in generic methods:
`static bool Foo<T> (T x, T y)
{
bool same = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals (x, y);`